# SQL concat column with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, concatenation, sql-server-2014, one-to-many

I would like some help creating an SQL sub statement which would show a concatenated string value using Table2 shown below:

[image: SQL concat tables]

For brevity see the following example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(Table2.TypeCode) ConcatField FROM Table1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, where does `Name` come from?

Comment: That's a really bad database design. Do you have any chance to fix it?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: That's not my database design - I published this example for simplicty. Thanks for tip though.

Answer (score 1):

This may be good:

```
WITH Concatetated AS (
    SELECT PrimaryId, '[' + STRING_AGG(TypeCode, '] [') + ']' AS "ConcatField"
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY PrimaryId
)

SELECT t1."PrimaryId", t1."Name", c."ConcatField"
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Concatetated c
  ON t1.PrimaryId = c.PrimaryId
```

Comment: Leszek, ATRING_AGG is not available in SQL-SERVER 2014.

Comment: Thanks for this Leszek - it was a great help, much appreciated. Ankit - We are due to upgrade our SQL servers so this job will have to wait. Thanks for the pointer.